# Fluent-Nhibernate + Web Api v2 + Unity

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, unity-container, asp.net-web-api-routing

Friends, I am using VS2013 and having issues with routing in my application.  I have created a very simple web application to illustrate my issue and have posted it to github here:

https://github.com/ewhitmore/RoutingIssues/

Currently i have one controller with GET, PUT, POST and DELETE verbs but when i try to use it, GET and POST work but DELETE and PUT do not.

I receive the following error: **"405 Method Not Allowed" and "message": "The requested resource does not support http method 'PUT'."**

I have put breakpoints on the controller and PUT/DELETE operations don't even make it to the controller.

I have used a AngularJS ng-resources , Postman and REST Console with the same result.

**I have uninstalled webdev from my computer**, tried a bunch of different routing techniques and nothing has worked.  This is all local and so not a cross site/server/domain (CORS) issue as far as i can tell.  At this point i have work over 20 hours on the issue and am about to give up.  Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

Code highlights below:

UserProfileContoller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Description;
using Microsoft.Practices.Unity;
using TrackInstant.Models.Entities;
using TrackInstant.Services;

namespace TrackInstant.Controllers
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [RoutePrefix("api/userprofile")]
    public class UserProfileController : ApiController
    {
        [Dependency]
        public UserProfileService UserProfileService { private get; set; }

        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<UserProfile> GetAllUsers()
        {
            return UserProfileService.GetAllUserProfiles();
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [ResponseType(typeof(UserProfile))]
        public UserProfile GetUserById(int id)
        {
            UserProfile userProfile = UserProfileService.GetUser(id);
            if (userProfile == null)
            {
                throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
            }
            return userProfile;
        }



        [HttpPost]
        [ResponseType(typeof(UserProfile))]
        public IHttpActionResult PostUser(UserProfile userProfile)
        {

            if (userProfile == null)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            UserProfileService.Save(userProfile);

            return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = userProfile.UserId }, userProfile);
        }

        [HttpPut]
        public IHttpActionResult PutUser(int id, UserProfile userProfile)
        {
            UserProfile persistentUser = UserProfileService.GetUser(id);
            if (persistentUser == null)
            {
                throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
            }
            persistentUser.Email = userProfile.Email;
            UserProfileService.UpdateUser(persistentUser);

            return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
        }

        [HttpDelete]
        [ResponseType(typeof(UserProfile))]
        public IHttpActionResult DeleteUser(int id)
        {
            UserProfile userProfile = UserProfileService.GetUser(id);
            if (userProfile == null)
            {
                throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
            }
            UserProfileService.DeleteUser(userProfile);

            return Ok(userProfile);
        }
    }
}
```

Web.config highlights:

```
<system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthenticationModule" />
      <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
    </modules>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="WebDAV" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
</handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

Global.asax

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Optimization;
using System.Web.Routing;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.SessionState;
using System.Web.Http;
using TrackInstant.App_Start;

namespace TrackInstant
{
    public class Global : HttpApplication
    {
        void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Code that runs on application startup

            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

            WebApiFilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Filters);


            HibernateConfig.InitHibernate();
            UnityBootstrapper.Initialise();





        }

        public override void Dispose()
        {
            HibernateConfig.SessionFactory.Dispose();
            base.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

RouteConfig

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Routing;
using Microsoft.AspNet.FriendlyUrls;


namespace TrackInstant
{
    public static class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {

            var settings = new FriendlyUrlSettings {AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent};
            routes.EnableFriendlyUrls(settings);
        }
    }
}
```

WebApiConfig

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Http;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;

namespace TrackInstant
{
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services

            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();


            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );



            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Clear();
            var formatters = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters;

            var jsonFormatter = formatters.JsonFormatter;
            jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.StringEnumConverter());

            var settings = jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings;
            settings.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
            settings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();

            config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
        }
    }
}
```

WebApiFilterConfig

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http.Filters;

namespace TrackInstant.App_Start
{
    public class WebApiFilterConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(HttpFilterCollection filters)
        {
            filters.Add(new HibernateSessionFilter());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the postman output for a put. Notice the "Allow": `Allow →GET,POST
Cache-Control →no-cache
Content-Length →79
Content-Type →application/json; charset=utf-8
Date →Tue, 17 Dec 2013 16:09:28 GMT
Expires →-1
Pragma →no-cache
Server →Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-AspNet-Version →4.0.30319
X-Powered-By →ASP.NET
X-SourceFiles →=?UTF-8?B?QzpcVXNlcnNcd2hpdG0xZWtcRG9jdW1lbnRzXFZpc3VhbCBTdHVkaW8gMjAxM1xQcm9qZWN0c1xSb3V0aW5nXFJvdXRpbmdJc3N1ZXNcVHJhY2tJbnN0YW50XGFwaVx1c2VycHJvZmlsZQ==?=`

Comment: I think if WebDAV is installed it can cause this problem.

Comment: Before posting I completely removed WebDAV from my computer.  Still no luck.

Comment: I don't believe it to be a "routing" configuration issue because a generic controller works just fine.  I can hit the breakpoints i set whereas with the userprofile controller it doesn't even reach the breakpoints.   [link]https://github.com/ewhitmore/RoutingIssues/blob/master/TrackInstant/Controllers/Default1Controller.cs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out!  There were two issues.

1. The PUT verb in my controller including an "int id" in the declaration.  This confusing the default routing because the url didn't include an ID in it during the post.  Changing the PUT declaration to the following fixed the issue:

   public IHttpActionResult PutUser(UserProfile userProfile)
2. The DELETE verb in my controller wasn't getting the correct input from postman or angularjs due to a typo.

Note to self: get more sleep and watch those URLs.

This is how my working controller looks:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Description;
using Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities;
using Microsoft.Practices.Unity;
using TrackInstant.Models.Entities;
using TrackInstant.Services;

namespace TrackInstant.Controllers
{

    public class UserProfileController : ApiController
    {
        [Dependency]
        public UserProfileService UserProfileService { private get; set; }


        public IEnumerable<UserProfile> GetAllUsers()
        {
            return UserProfileService.GetAllUserProfiles();
        }

        public UserProfile GetUserById(int id)
        {
            UserProfile userProfile = UserProfileService.GetUser(id);
            if (userProfile == null)
            {
                throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
            }
            return userProfile;
        }

        public IHttpActionResult PostUser(UserProfile userProfile)
        {

            if (userProfile == null)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            UserProfileService.Save(userProfile);

            return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = userProfile.UserId }, userProfile);
        }


        public IHttpActionResult PutUser(UserProfile userProfile)
        {
            UserProfile persistentUser = UserProfileService.GetUser(userProfile.UserId);
            if (persistentUser == null)
            {
                throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
            }
            persistentUser.Email = userProfile.Email;
            UserProfileService.UpdateUser(persistentUser);

            return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
        }


        public IHttpActionResult DeleteUser(int id)
        {
            UserProfile persistentUser = UserProfileService.GetUser(id);
            if (persistentUser == null)
            {
                throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
            }
            UserProfileService.DeleteUser(persistentUser);

            return Ok(persistentUser);
        }
    }
}
```